# Using Between with Max?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, max, between

is it possible to use Between with Max, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID BETWEEN 100 AND MAX
```

Or a way to go to the end?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Why not just `where ID >= 100`?

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'max'.

Comment: What is the point of selecting between 100 and max ? Basically >= 100.

Comment: @ray i wouldn't be asking this question. =)

Comment: @ZeeTee well you need to explain why you can't do that. And what the difference would be.

Comment: @ZeeTee Nobody understands what you want to do. You need to explain it better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

below will work

```
SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE id BETWEEN 100 and (SELECT MAX(id) from tblName)
```

Comment: You had the most relevant, but unfortunately I had to restructure some code anyway.. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by Max? The maximum value of the data type? The maximum value in the column?

In any case you just need

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID >= 100
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why you wouldn't just use a greater-than-or-equal-to condition, but if you really insist on doing it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID BETWEEN 100 AND (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out you can use a nested select to get the MAX value for the end of your range

Here is a code sample to test out the theory:

```
create table #TempTable (id int)
declare @Counter int
set @Counter = 1
while (@Counter < 1000)
begin 

    insert into #TempTable (id) values (@Counter)
    set @Counter = @Counter + 1
end

select * from #TempTable where id between 800 and (Select MAX(id) from #TempTable)
drop table #TempTable
```